# How do I setup a CMake project with both Allegro and MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, allegro

Lately I've been experimenting with the *Allegro* game library, but I'm having some trouble setting it up in the following scenario:

I would like to create a cross-platform project (for at least Linux and Windows binaries, preferably also OS X) using CMake that utilizes the Allegro game library, but is able to build using MSVC instead of MinGW for the Windows Binaries.

I tried linking statically to the MinGW standard libraries, but the supplied Allegro binaries for MinGW are still dynamically linked, so I'd rather just use the proper Windows compiler.

Does anyone know if it is possible to extract the binaries from the Nuget package or if there's a more proper way to use MSVC and Allegro while still maintaining a cross-platform source code?

I'd prefer not having to build Allegro from source, but if I have to, any links to guides would be helpful.

Comment: Each compiler you use will have different binaries. Mingw is incompatible with msvc for c++ projects. I believe your focus on binaries is a wrong approach.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. The question for Allegro specifically: is there any way to get MSVC binaries without using Nuget? As far as I understand that limits my ability to use CMake and MSVC?

Comment: allegro is in vcpkg: [https://vcpkg.info/port/allegro5](https://vcpkg.info/port/allegro5) you may want to make vcpkg a requirement and use it on all platforms you will be developing your code

Comment: @drescherjm ah this is great, thanks!